# "http post to amazon web server through esp8266

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, arduino, http-post, arduino-esp8266

"level-noob"

So, I am trying to save data to the table created in the amazon server through Http post.I tried hitting it through postman and resource get created but while trying to achieve the same through I am not getting anything neither any response, I tried posting to other sources like ptsv2.com and it hitting there,.not able to figure out what's wrong.

I tried hitting it through postman getting id appended in return and tried this code to some other server it's hitting there don't know what wrong with this aws server.

```
//host and url are bit changed

WiFiClient client;
const int httpPort = 80;
 if (!client.connect(host, httpPort)) 
{
   Serial.println("connection failed");
   return;
  }


         String postStr ;
         postStr +="posts={\n\"date\":\"";
         postStr += String(date);
         postStr +="\",\n\"time\":\"";
         postStr += String(Time);
         postStr +="\",\n\"dev_mac_id\":\"";
         postStr += String(dev_mac_id);
         postStr +="\",\n\"sensor_id1\":\"";
         postStr += String(sensor_id1);
         postStr +="\",\n\"value1\":\"";
         postStr += String(value1);
         postStr +="\",\n\"sensor_id2\":\"";
         postStr += String(sensor_id2);
         postStr +="\",\n\"value2\":\"";
         postStr += String(value2);

         postStr +="\",\n\"sensor_id3\":\"";
         postStr += String(sensor_id3);
         postStr +="\",\n\"value3\":\"";
         postStr += String(value3);
           postStr +="\",\n\"sensor_id4\":\"";
         postStr += String(sensor_id4);
         postStr +="\",\n\"value4\":\"";
         postStr += String(value4);

         postStr +="\",\n\"dev_helth_status\":";
          postStr +="\"active\"";
         postStr +="\n}";
         postStr += "\r\n\r\n";
         Serial.print(postStr);

  Serial.print("Requesting POST: ");
 // Send request to the server:
 client.println("POST /dev/post HTTP/1.1");`enter code here`
 client.println("Host: ce58f198zeb.execute-api.ap-west- 
 13.amazonaws.com");
  client.println("Cache-Control: no-cache");
  client.println("Accept: */*");
 client.println("Content-Type: application/json");
 client.print("Content-Length: ");
  client.println(postStr.length());
  client.println();
  client.print(postStr);
  String answer=getResponse();
  Serial.println(answer);


  delay(500); // Can be changed
  if (client.connected()) 
    { 
   client.stop();  // DISCONNECT FROM THE SERVER
    Serial.print("taking off ");
    }
   Serial.println();
    Serial.println("closing connection");
   delay(5000);


   }
  String getResponse(){
  String response;
  long startTime = millis();

  delay( 200 );
    while ( client.available() < 1 && (( millis() - startTime ) < TIMEOUT 
  ) ){
    delay( 5 );
     }

   Serial.println(client.available()+",");
  if( client.available() > 0 ){ // Get response from server.
 char charIn;
 do {
     charIn = client.read(); // Read a char from the buffer.
     response += charIn;     // Append the char to the string response.
    } while ( client.available() > 0 );
   }
    client.stop();

   return response;
    }


 //json espected format

  {
   "date":"12/11/11",
    "time":"22:11:11",
    "dev_mac_id":"1111",
     "sensor_id1":"121",
      "value1":"42",
      "sensor_id2":"122",
       "value2":"43",
        "sensor_id3":"123",
       "value3":"22",
        "sensor_id4":"124",
        "value4":"32",
       "dev_helth_status":"active"
       }
```

Comment: what is in `host`? does the server accept insecure HTTP?

Comment: yes ,server accept inscecure http i tried hitting through post using http